# How to filter a dataframe column having multiple values in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that sometimes has multiple values in cells like this:

```
df:
Fruits
apple, pineapple, mango
guava, blueberry, apple
custard-apple, cranberry
banana, kiwi, peach
apple
```

Now, I want to filter the data frame having an apple in the value.
So my output should look like this:

```
Fruits
apple, pineapple, mango
guava, blueberry, apple
apple
```

I used the str.contains('apple') but this is not returning the ideal result.

Can anyone help me with how I can get this result?

Comment: Please show us your code and the current output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the data by `,`, explode them, then compare with `apple`:

```
mask = df['Fruits'].str.split(', ').explode().eq('apple').groupby(level=0).any()
df[mask]
```

Output:

```
                    Fruits
0  apple, pineapple, mango
1  guava, blueberry, apple
4                    apple
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.query](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) with [.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

```
import pandas as pd


data = {
    "Fruits": ["apple, pineapple, mango", "guava, blueberry, apple", "custard-apple, cranberry",
               "banana, kiwi, peach", "apple"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.query("Fruits.str.contains('apple') & ~Fruits.str.contains('-apple')").reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)

                    Fruits
0  apple, pineapple, mango
1  guava, blueberry, apple
2                    apple
```

Comment: What if there is a row with `custard-apple, apple`. Also a row with `pear, pineapple`?

Comment: ah right, good point

Answer (score -1):

Here you go,

```
apple = df[df.values == "apple"] 
print("The df with apple:", apple)
```

[image]

[image]